# Spring Security Max Login Session

Tags: spring-security

I have a problem with my j2ee application using spring security. I set max-sessions in concurrent-session-control to 1. Now it works fine when I try to Login the second time it will stop me. But when I logout the other one and try to login again I still get this same message.

Your login attempt was not successful, try again.
Reason: Maximum sessions of 1 for this principal exceeded

I have this in my http security

```
 <security:logout logout-url="/logout.do"
  invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/logoutSuccess.do" />
 <security:concurrent-session-control
  max-sessions="1" exception-if-maximum-exceeded="true" expired-url="/loginform.do" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's been quite a while since you posted this, but if anyone else is having this problem I believe this behavior will occur if you don't add `org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher` as a listener in your web.xml.

See [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/session-mgmt.html#d0e3816):

> Adding the listener to web.xml causes an ApplicationEvent to be published to the Spring ApplicationContext every time a HttpSession commences or terminates. This is critical, as it allows the SessionRegistryImpl  to be notified when a session ends. Without it, a user will never be able to log back in again once they have exceeded their session allowance, even if they log out of another session or it times out.

Answer (score 0):

please check that the error page is not cached (press F5) and look in the logs to see if the logout is working fine.

Comment: I pressed F5 and the message is still there. What does it mean

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your Spring Security Filters run before your Struts Filter.
2. Set a break point at Spring Security's [LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ui/logout/LogoutFilter.html) method.  Make sure that part runs properly.